# How to de-nested a list of list of dictionary into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a list of list of dictionary like this

```
['[{"date_update":"31-03-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.0"}]',  

'[{"date_update":"28-04-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.5"}]', 

'[{"date_update":"25-12-2021","diemquatrinh":"6.0"}, {"date_update":"28-04-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.25"},{"date_update":"28-07-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.5"}]',

'[{"date_update":null,"diemquatrinh":null}]']
```

I don't know how to make them into a DataFrame with 2 columns like this. I'm looking forward to your help. Thank you!

| **updated_at** | **diemquatrinh** |
| --- | --- |
| 11-03-2022 | 6.25 |
| 25-12-2021 | 6.0 |
| 28-04-2022 | 6.25 |
| 28-07-2022 | 6.5 |
| null | null |

Comment: Each element in the outer list/array is a `string` or a proper `list`?

Comment: The data you've presented looks like a single list of strings. Is this your actual data, or do you mean to present a single list of sublists, each sublist containing a single dictionary of two keys each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert strings to dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

example_data=['[{"date_update":"31-03-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.0"}]',  

'[{"date_update":"28-04-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.5"}]', 

'[{"date_update":"25-12-2021","diemquatrinh":"6.0"}, {"date_update":"28-04-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.25"},{"date_update":"28-07-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.5"}]',

'[{"date_update":null,"diemquatrinh":null}]']

listt=[]
for i in example_data:
    listt.append(json.loads(i))
```

when i examine the data, each dictionary has the same keys. This means I can collect all dictionaries in one list.

```
main_list = [item for sublist in listt for item in sublist]
print(main_list)
'''
[{'date_update': '31-03-2022', 'diemquatrinh': '6.0'}, {'date_update': '28-04-2022', 'diemquatrinh': '6.5'}, {'date_update': '25-12-2021', 'diemquatrinh': '6.0'}, {'date_update': '28-04-2022', 'diemquatrinh': '6.25'}, {'date_update': '28-07-2022', 'diemquatrinh': '6.5'}, {'date_update': None, 'diemquatrinh': None}]
'''
```

All that's left is to convert the list to a dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(main_list)
print(df)
'''
    date_update diemquatrinh
0   31-03-2022  6.0
1   28-04-2022  6.5
2   25-12-2021  6.0
3   28-04-2022  6.25
4   28-07-2022  6.5
5   None        None

'''
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code work perfectly. Could you please help me with another similar question, but harder. This is a link to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426788/how-to-convert-dictionary-with-multiple-keys-values-pairs-to-dataframe.