# How to convert dictionary with multiple keys-values pairs to DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I try to clean the data with this code

```
empty = {}
    mess = lophoc_clean.query("lop_diemquatrinh.notnull()")[['lop_id', 'lop_diemquatrinh']]
    keys = []
    values = []
    for index, rows  in mess.iterrows():
        if len(rows['lop_diemquatrinh']) >4:
            values.append(rows['lop_diemquatrinh'])
            keys.append(rows['lop_id'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(keys, values)), index = [0]).transpose()
    df.columns = ['data']
```

The result is a dictionary like this

```
     {'data': {37: '[{"date_update":"31-03-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.0"}]',
      38: '[{"date_update":"11-03-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.25"}]',
      44: '[{"date_update":"25-12-2021","diemquatrinh":"6.0"},{"date_update":"28-04-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.25"},{"date_update":"28-07-2022","diemquatrinh":"6.5"}]',
      1095: '[{"date_update":null,"diemquatrinh":null}]'}}
```

However, I don't know how to make them into a DataFrame with 3 columns like this. Please help me. Thank you!

| **id** | **updated_at** | **diemquatrinh** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 11-03-2022 | 6.25 |
| 44 | 25-12-2021 | 6.0 |
| 44 | 28-04-2022 | 6.25 |
| 44 | 28-07-2022 | 6.5 |
| 1095 | null | null |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Have you written any code? Are you getting any errors? How do your results differ from your desired output? Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ddejohn Thank you for your recommendation. I edited the question, adding more context to it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
from json import loads
from pprint import pp

import pandas as pd


def get_example_data():
    return [
        dict(id=38, updated_at="2022-03-11", diemquatrinh=6.25),
        dict(id=44, updated_at="2021-12-25", diemquatrinh=6),
        dict(id=44, updated_at="2022-04-28", diemquatrinh=6.25),
        dict(id=1095, updated_at=None),
    ]


df = pd.DataFrame(get_example_data())
df["updated_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["updated_at"])

print(df.dtypes, "\n")
pp(loads(df.to_json()))
print()
print(df, "\n")
pp(loads(df.to_json(orient="records")))
```

It produces this output:

```
id                       int64
updated_at      datetime64[ns]
diemquatrinh           float64
dtype: object 

{'id': {'0': 38, '1': 44, '2': 44, '3': 1095},
 'updated_at': {'0': 1646956800000,
                '1': 1640390400000,
                '2': 1651104000000,
                '3': None},
 'diemquatrinh': {'0': 6.25, '1': 6.0, '2': 6.25, '3': None}}

     id updated_at  diemquatrinh
0    38 2022-03-11          6.25
1    44 2021-12-25          6.00
2    44 2022-04-28          6.25
3  1095        NaT           NaN 

[{'id': 38, 'updated_at': 1646956800000, 'diemquatrinh': 6.25},
 {'id': 44, 'updated_at': 1640390400000, 'diemquatrinh': 6.0},
 {'id': 44, 'updated_at': 1651104000000, 'diemquatrinh': 6.25},
 {'id': 1095, 'updated_at': None, 'diemquatrinh': None}]
```

Either of the JSON datastructures
would be acceptable input
for creating a new DataFrame from scratch.

Comment: thank you @J_H, your code works!, but I fail to see how it can be reproducible for a larger data.

Comment: A list-of-dicts is a very common representation for Big Data apps that use dataframes. Here's two ways we often see it introduced into code: (1.) def my_generator: while True: yield dict( ... ), and (2.) SELECT * FROM my_table; Keep reading DB rows, each row is a namedtuple or similar, which fits right into a dataframe. But hey, if you're not fond of that approach, really there's nothing wrong with writing out long CSV files and pulling them in with read_csv(). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html Use `io.StringIO` if you want to keep it in memory.